# endorsed dir mechanism not working?

Tags: java, java-8, endorsed

I need to debug something happening inside JDK 1.8 classes. I'm trying to use the **endorsed** dir mechanism mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/), but doesn't seem to be working for me. This is what I did (on Windows):

1. copied the `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI` class source code into `<JDK_HOME>/jre/lib/endorsed/javax/swing/plaf/basic/`
2. Modified the class code, adding:

   ```
   static {
       System.out.println("REPLACED BasicListUI");
   }
   ```

   I expect this to cause the message to be printed as soon as the class is loaded.
3. cd to `<JDK_HOME>/jre/lib/endorsed` and run `javac javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicListUI`. This results in the `BasicListUI.class` file generated in the same dir as the source file.
4. wrote, and compiled this program:

   ```
   import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI;
   public class t {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));
           System.out.println(BasicListUI.class.getResource("BasicListUI.class"));
       }
   }
   ```
5. executed program with `java t`. I don't see the `REPLACED BasicListUI` message, and the output of the program is:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\endorsed
   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicListUI.class
   ```

Also, if I run:

```
$ java -verbose t | grep BasicListUI
```

The output is:

```
[Loaded javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar] jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/swing    /plaf/basic/BasicListUI.class
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/ - it says `Packages to be updated through this mechanism should be placed in JAR files.` so maybe just putting .class files in there doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found the problem. The classes have to be packaged in a jar file. so, added

6. `jar cvf rt.jar javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicListUI.class`

Comment: But note that the “endorsed-standards override” feature [is going to die anyway](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml)…